# Scroll effect on website?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I saw this website online: http://manipal.edu/mu.html, I have only one question, is it difficult to create a scroll effect like this and what's the name of it? And how do I only activate him on scroll? It there a library for this or something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you referenced is most likely doing this with Javascript/jQuery by listening to multiple scroll and touch events. Once you know the user has attempted to scroll you determine which direction was intended and then navigate the page appropriately.

Hijacking the users scroll functionality is frowned upon by a lot of developers and users though. It can be very annoying especially when the user is trying to navigate your page quickly (I've ready blog posts about this but can't find any atm to use as a source).

This effect was made popular by Apple in both their iPhone 5 and [Mac Pro](https://www.apple.com/mac-pro/) sites. But these sites were built to be presentational.

There is a library named [One Page Scroll](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) that can be used to duplicate the effect you're looking for.